# Symbol vs. String when retrieving property from target object, using ES6 Proxy object

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-proxy

Using the following code:

```
 const assrt = function () {
    try {
      return chaiAssert.apply(null, arguments);
    }
    catch (e) {
      return handleError(e);
    }
  };

 v.assert = new Proxy(assrt, {
    get: function (target, prop) {

      if(typeof prop === 'symbol'){
        // I don't know what to do with symbols, so return
         return Reflect.get(...arguments);
      }

      // but here! we still get properties that don't exist
      if(!chaiAssert[prop]){
        return handleError(
          new Error(`The assertion library used does not have '${prop}' property or method.`)
        );
      }

      return function () {
        try {
          return chaiAssert[prop].apply(null, arguments);
        }
        catch (e) {
          return handleError(e);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

the error I get with this code is:

> TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

and this occurs on the line:

```
new Error(`The assertion library used does not have '${prop}' property or method.`));
```

I have used Proxies before, and I have never seen Symbols being passed to the get method of the Proxy. Does anyone know how to circumvent this problem?

**Why are Symbols being passed to the Proxy get function and how do I properly handle that?**

Comment: the prop that's being sent to the get function is `Symbol(util.inspect.custom)`, and think there are others that get sent as well.

Comment: I think, you have to debug the code. It doesn't seem like symbols have to be filtered out by `if(typeof prop === 'symbol'){`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are Symbols being passed to the Proxy get function?

We don't know, you didn't show any code that actually *uses* the proxy. But many symbols are accessed by builtin methods, e.g. when you iterate the proxy it uses the `Symbol.iterator` method.

> and how do I properly handle that?

You cannot concatenate a symbol with a string, you need to be explicit about doing this. You can use either `prop.toString()` or just switch based on `typeof prop`.

Comment: can you demonstrate what you mean by switching on typeof prop

Comment: `typeof prop == "symbol" ? "Symbol ["+prop.toString()+"]" : prop` or whatever you want to do with symbols. Maybe just ignore them completely in your proxy handler and just respond with the default `Reflect.get` for them.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what to do with the symbols but I need to pass back what they are looking for when the symbols get passed...can you show how to use Reflect as you suggest?

Comment: looks like this => `return Reflect.get(...arguments)`

Comment: I am so confused why a non-symbol property would get passed to the handler's get method, and the target property would not exist on the target. I will update the OP.

Comment: In "*but here! we still get properties that don't exist*", do you mean that you still get an exception from stringification attempts on symbols, or that `handleError` gets called? In either case, please post a [mcve] with the whole code you are executing.

Comment: I am going to have to update you later if the problem re-appears, I frankly don't know what was happening.